# Ancestry Tree Gem: Scoping Records by foreign key to improve performance?

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, ancestry

I am using the ruby gem Ancestry (https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) to model a refer-a-friend "pay it forward"-like structure.

Within my table, I create many different trees, unique to a foreign key, event_id. Each event_id has one root node, and then descendants off of that.

I currently have indexes:

```
add_index :promoters, :ancestry
add_index :promoters, :event_id
```

Simple.

Queries are becoming quite slow... upwards of 350ms to query 1st-child level nodes.

I'm wondering if its best to create a new index, like,

```
add_index :promoters, [:event_id, :ancestry]
```

My understanding is that this could dramatically speed up the LIKE queries, as it can reduce the table down to the records of the event_id first.

Database is Postgres, Rails 4.1, on Heroku.

Thanks, and if there are any alternative/better ways, please suggest them.

Edit: adding more information about the LIKE queries

Querying first level nodes:

```
ancestry = '22333433'
```

Querying all descendants (indirect) of a node:

```
ancestry LIKE '22333433/%'
```

The gem basically stores the path to the node as a string, separating the ids of the nodes to get to this node with '/'

Comment: LIKE queries? What does the `ancestry` column look like? Does this gem use some sort of "portable" CSV-in-a-column monstrosity by chance? Also, what sort of SQL queries does ancestry produce? You'll need to know how things work at the SQL level if you want to have any hope of optimizing this stuff.

Comment: I added some more information about how the ancestry column works

Comment: Do you have to use ancestry? Maybe do some research on "trees in SQL" and pick the one that fits your usage pattern the best (and pay attention to representations that want to use recursive CTEs since PostgreSQL supports those).